# using nested_form with bootstrap table not styling properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-form-for

I have the following code to create a nested model (invoice_line_items) within my invoice model:

```
    = nested_form_for @invoice, mutipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" do |f|

    ...

    %table.table.table-bordered{:id => "line-items"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th
          %th Description
          %th Quantity
          %th Rate
      %tbody
        %tr
          = f.fields_for :invoice_line_items do |line_item|
            %td= line_item.link_to_remove "X"
            %td= line_item.text_field :description
            %td= line_item.text_field :quantity, :class => "input-mini"
            %td= line_item.text_field :rate, :class => "input-mini"
    = f.link_to_add "Add", :invoice_line_items, :data => { :target => "#line-items" }
```

I have two problems: 1) when I add a new row by clicking "Add"....it doesn't match the table formatting and doesn't insert into the table. I tried everything to get it to work and it just doesn't. I also tried adding the ":target" as mentioned by ryanb in his gem docs. 2) I would like to have 3 invoice_line_items initially ready for the user on the invoice page, but i'm not sure how to do that.

EDIT: I got something a little different now since I've been playing around with it. I don't think i'm doing it right still but now it creates a new form each time I click "add":

```
    .row-fluid
  = f.fields_for :invoice_line_items, :wrapper => false do |line_item|
    %table.table.table-bordered#tasks
      %thead
        %th
        %th Description
        %th Quantity
        %th Rate
      %tr.fields
        %td= line_item.link_to_remove "X"
        %td= line_item.text_field :description
        %td= line_item.text_field :quantity, :class => "input-mini"
        %td= line_item.text_field :rate, :class => "input-mini"
  .row-fluid
    = f.link_to_add "Add", :invoice_line_items, :data => { :target => "#tasks" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a tough one to figure out but it turns out that the most updated version of the nested_form gem doesn't come with the most recent version of the jquery_nested_form.js file (even though the documentation says to use this function). So, to get this to work, I had to add this to my application.js:

```
$(function ($) {
  window.NestedFormEvents.prototype.insertFields = function(content, assoc, link) {
    var target = $(link).data('target');
    if (target) {
      return $(content).appendTo($(target));
    } else {
      return $(content).insertBefore(link);
    }
  };
});
```

this overwrote the function in jquery_nested_form.js and now everything works.